# Is there a way to append data to a hdfs file using Pydoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to write contents of an object to a file in hdfs using python. For this, I have found a hdfs API implemented in python named Pydoop. Reading the API, I can easily use `dump()` method of pydoop to write contents to a file in hdfs path but have not seen any method like `append()` that could append new content to the old file. I know it is possible as I have found command line syntax for hdfs that does this but was thinking of using pydoop for doing this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: HDFS files aren't really meant to be appended to. Why can't you fetch the file, write to it locally, then push it back?

Comment: Well, my files are supposed to be large. So if i fetch the file write it locally and push again, there will be a lot of overhead involved in between because of network which may not be efficient.

Comment: Alright, then evoke the command line function from Python

Comment: Are you saying to use subprocess module to start a new process with the hdfs command line syntax to append content to hdfs file ?

Comment: Assuming you cannot find an alternative, then yes

Comment: That was my alternative but was wondering if someone knows how to do this by using pydoop or some other python module

Comment: Have you tried `pydoop.hdfs.open(hdfs_path, 'a')`?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Pydoop, but this reads just like the Python API for appending to a regular file.

```
from pydoop import hdfs

with hdfs.open('/path/to/file', 'a') as f:
    f.write('bla')
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, if mode "a" is allowed for open() method of pydoop hdfs api or not. Documentation doesn't specify anything except that default value is  "r".

Comment: Well, let me know what you find out. I don't have a machine I can test against right now

Comment: I tried it with 'a'. it did not work at all, no changes.
I tried it with 'w', it just writes a blank file.

Comment: @Taylor Did you flush/close the file ?

Comment: Thanks, adding .close() makes 'w' work. 
I still cannot get "a" to work not matter how i try.  only "w"/"wb"/"r"/"rb" seem to work.
maybe there is some problem with underlying hdfs imp/perms